# Appcelerator ArrowDB smtp mail configuration

Tags: email, appcelerator, arrowdb

So, I have an app in the Appcelerator platform and I wish to use the reset password feature.

I need to configure SMTP settings in the platform.

What I have is a server that has STARTTLS and port 587.

I have tried all sorts of things but Appcelerator keeps saying the SMTP settings are not valid.

Anyone have a clue?

Comment: If you are sure that the SMTP server is valid then it looks like you've found a bug. Thanks for that! Could you check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, please create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Answer (score 0):

I’m trying to figure out what is the issue when saving the SMTP form on ArrowDB (console)… From what I can figure out… after you save the SMTP settings… you have to paste the password Again, and then Save again, then it works.